# how do i check for the existence of a method in a rails application controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

In my application controller, I have a method that is supposed to check for the existence of another method in a subclassed controller to set the filename of a downloaded file, but i'm having trouble making it work properly

i've tried

```
def filename
  begin
    send "filename_method"
  rescue NoMethodError
    default_filename
  end
end
```

and

```
def filename
 if respond_to?("filename_method")
  send "filename_method"
 else
  default_filename
 end
end
```

but both always return default_filename, even if filename_method is defined in the subclassed controller.  Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Thanks,

-C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this is due to the fact that the controller superclass does not know of the existence of the subclass's methods. You can confirm this by inspecting the `methods` array of the subclass.

It seems like the solution is to reconsider your design. Instead of checking for the existence of `filename_method`, just provide the default filename behavior in the base `filename` method and override the `filename` method in the subclass to provide custom filename functionality.

For example, in your superclass:

```
def filename
  # return default file name 
end
```

And in your subclass:

```
def filename
  # return custom file name 
end
```

Comment: lol, duh, I should have thought of that in the first place, thanks :)

-C